# If $f$ is differentiable, then there is a unique linear transformation

Tags: real-analysis

From Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds, p.16:
[image]

I didn't understand the last two lines. **Why is it true that**
$$
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\mid\lambda(tx)-\mu(tx)\mid}{\mid tx\mid}=\frac{\mid\lambda(x)-\mu(x)\mid}{\mid x\mid}
$$? I always thought that $h$ stands for $x-a$, in which case $t=1-\dfrac{a}{x}$ but this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Both $\mu$ and $\lambda$ are linear.

Comment: Which means as $t\to 0$, $\lambda(tx),\mu(tx)\to 0$, but then what? Why did he introduce $t$?

Comment: I didn't read the proof, but judging by [dls](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/1761/dls)'s [comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489409/if-f-is-differentiable-then-there-is-a-unique-linear-transformation#comment1053205_489409) above, he means that $\mu (tx)=t\mu (x)$ and similarly for$\lambda$.

Comment: Ah, great! Then the $|t|$'s cancel and the result follows. Thank you

Comment: No problem. I suggest you answer your own question so this doesn't come up as unanswered. By the way, I've read the proof now and in fact dls is correct. I should point out that the author only proves that there is at most one such linear transformation. He doesn't prove there actually is one.